# Put folder in theme via plugin

Tags: plugins

I've created a set of customisations for WordPress and turned these into a very simple plugin. As part of this customisation process I also need to manually ftp a folder containing css and some images, to the theme folder.

Is it possible to package this folder with my plugin and have the plugin move the folder over to the required location(s)?

If so, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be thinking about this in the wrong sense.  What are you using the CSS and images for?  You should be using `wp_enqueue_script/wp_register_script` for css and the images would be specific to your use case.

You can just use PHP built in functions to copy files:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php